# Are there any ship design rules for star wars ships?

Tags: star-wars-d6

I THINK I have seen them in the past once, but not sure any longer if I'm not confusing it with the D20 version. Were there any ship design rules published for the star wars D6?

Answer (score 2):

### D20

If you want a straightforward construction guide try to find the original  [Starships of the Galaxy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starships_of_the_Galaxy) (modification is swiped under the rug).  If your prefer that the players modify a ship to their liking instead of designing it from scratch, get the [Saga edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starships_of_the_Galaxy_(Saga_Edition)).

You can use either book to do the other (ie use the D20 book to distill modifications out of it or use the Saga version to get a construction guide), but that can be more hassle than it's worth.

### D6

No details here with regards to constructing a ship, but there's plenty to do with modification (with good or bad results). Any of the core rulebook editions contains a section about starships, but if you want to have the full package then you need:

- [Stock Ships](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stock_Ships): to have basic information for various ships. The biggest bonus here is that you get deck plans!
- [Galaxy Guide 6: Tramp Freighters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_Guide_6:_Tramp_Freighters) and [Pirates & Privateers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_%26_Privateers): for various ship modification options.
- If you want to have a description of the Millenium Falcon, get [Han Solo and the Corporate Sector Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_and_the_Corporate_Sector_Sourcebook).

With that, you wont have everything (ship descriptions are very spread out in D6), but you'll have a very stable basis. You can also get the [Death Star Technical Companion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_Technical_Companion) if that's what you fancy. .

Answer (score 2):

## for D6

Try [this one](http://krapz.free.fr/data/Starships_Pricing.pdf):

credits:
*"Star Wars Starship Pricing and alterations created by Krapou 2006, based on original Starship Generation created by Grimace 2002, both systems based loosely on the format originally listed in WOTC’s Starships of the Galaxy"*

So it seems to be a D6 conversion of the D20 / Saga reference cited by Ahriman.

Krapou is from the Rancor Pit. Krapou's work was subsenquently [cited by Fallon Kell](http://www.rancorpit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3707&sid=04200a01c3be46269b7451894652ea36) (another guy at The Rancor Pit) who issued the SCS (Fallon Kell's Starship Construction System)